# Is it possible to install custom Ansible plugin from git

Tags: ansible

I'd like to share a custom inventory plugin across multiple playbooks and users.

Is it possible to host a custom inventory plugin on git and the like roles with `requirements.yml` do something like:

```sh
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

I tried to embbed it in a role using:

```sh
/myrole/library/inventory_plugins/custom_inventory.py
/myrole/plugins/inventory_plugins/custom_inventory.py
/myrole/inventory_plugins/custom_inventory.py
```

but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Is it possible to install custom Ansible plugin from git?"*

A: Yes. It's possible. For example

1) Download and extract the plugins

```
  vars:

    ma_src_path: "/usr/local/ansible/src"
    ma_plugins_path: "/usr/local/ansible/plugins"
    map_mitogen_ver: 0.2.8                                                                        
    map_mitogen_sha256: "sha256:1bfca66bcc522346c9167a3a9829feac5ee3b84431e49354fb780e4b9a4b0eee"

    ma_plugins:                                                                                   
      - archive: mitogen-{{ map_mitogen_ver }}.tar.gz                                             
        archive_url: https://networkgenomics.com/try/mitogen-{{ map_mitogen_ver }}.tar.gz         
        checksum: "{{ map_mitogen_sha256 }}"                                                      
        plugins:                                                                                  
          - path: mitogen-{{ map_mitogen_ver }}/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy                  
            ini_key: strategy_plugins                                                             
            enable: true                                                                          

  tasks:

    - name: "plugins: Download archives"
      get_url:
        url: "{{ item.archive_url }}"
        dest: "{{ ma_src_path }}"
        checksum: "{{ item.checksum }}"
      loop: "{{ ma_plugins }}"

    - name: "plugins: Extract archives"
      unarchive:
        src: "{{ ma_src_path }}/{{ item.archive }}"
        dest: "{{ ma_plugins_path }}"
      loop: "{{ ma_plugins }}"
```

2) Configure the plugins with template [ansible-plugins.cfg.j2](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-ansible/blob/master/templates/ansible-plugins.cfg.j2)

```
  vars:

    ma_config:
      - path: "/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg"
        template: "ansible-plugins.cfg.j2"
        owner: "root"
        group: "root"
        mode: "0644"
        config:
         - { section: "defaults", key: "inventory", value: "/etc/ansible/hosts" }
         - { section: "defaults", key: "strategy", value: "mitogen_linear" }

  tasks:

    - name: "configure: Ansible configuration from template"
      template:
        src: "{{ item.template }}"
        dest: "{{ item.path }}"
        owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
        group: "{{ item.group }}"
        mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
        backup: "{{ ma_backup_conf }}"
      loop: "{{ ma_config }}"
      when: ma_config|length > 0
```

See the complete role at [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/ansible).